# Dropdown not showing up within Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My dropdown menu does not show in my wp website, when I hover my mouse. I tried adding this?

```
.sub-menu .navigation {
  display: block;
  height: 0px;
  z-index: 63;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Still it didn't help.

Comment: have you tried :onhover ?

Comment: Yes I also tried that but still didn't work.

Comment: Please show us the url of site so i can review it.

Comment: I have downloaded a plugin for the dropdown menu and its functioning properly.